# How do I pass an array to a function in Rust and change its content?

Tags: arrays, rust

I want to pass an array to a function and change the content inside it:

```rust
fn change_value(mut arr: &[i32]) {
    arr[1] = 10;
}

fn main() {
    let mut arr: [i32; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    change_value(&arr);
    println!("this is {}", arr[1]);
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
 --> src/main.rs:2:17
  |
2 | fn change_value(mut arr: &[i32]) {
  |                 ----^^^
  |                 |
  |                 help: remove this `mut`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

error[E0594]: cannot assign to `arr[_]` which is behind a `&` reference
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
2 | fn change_value(mut arr: &[i32]) {
  |                          ------ help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut [i32]`
3 |     arr[1] = 10;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ `arr` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be written

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |     let mut arr: [i32; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  |         ----^^^
  |         |
  |         help: remove this `mut`
```

I've been searching around, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Rust references (denoted by the `&` sign) are of two kinds: immutable (`&T`) and mutable (`&mut T`). In order to change the value behind the reference, this reference has to be mutable, so you need to:

1. accept `&mut [i32]` as the function argument, not `&[i32]`
2. pass `&mut arr` to the function, not `&arr`:

```rust
fn change_value(arr: &mut [i32]) {
    arr[1] = 10;
}

fn main() {
    let mut arr: [i32; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    change_value(&mut arr);
    println!("this is {}", arr[1]);
}
```

You don't need `mut arr` in `change_value`'s argument because `mut` there denotes mutability of that variable, not of the data it points to. With `mut arr: &[i32]` you can reassign `arr` itself (for it to point to a different slice), but you can't change the data it references.

If you wanted to accept an *array* instead of a *slice*, you could also do that:

```rust
fn change_value(arr: &mut [i32; 4]) {
    arr[1] = 10;
}
```

See also:

- [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/155423)