# What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?

Tags: variables, syntax, reference, rust, mutable

Here are two function signatures I saw in the Rust documentation:

```
fn modify_foo(mut foo: Box<i32>) { *foo += 1; *foo }
fn modify_foo(foo: &mut i32) { *foo += 1; *foo }
```

Why the different placement of `mut`?

It seems that the first function could also be declared as

```
fn modify_foo(foo: mut Box<i32>) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: For C++ programmers: the difference is similar to [pointer `const` vs `pointee` const](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21476869/183120).

Answer (score 142, accepted):

`mut foo: T` means you have a variable called `foo` that is a `T`. You are allowed to change what the variable **refers to**:

```
let mut val1 = 2;
val1 = 3; // OK

let val2 = 2;
val2 = 3; // error: re-assignment of immutable variable
```

This also lets you modify fields of a struct that you own:

```
struct Monster { health: u8 }

let mut orc = Monster { health: 93 };
orc.health -= 54;

let goblin = Monster { health: 28 };
goblin.health += 10; // error: cannot assign to immutable field
```

`foo: &mut T` means you have a variable that refers to (`&`) a value and you are allowed to change (`mut`) the **referred value** (including fields, if it is a struct):

```
let val1 = &mut 2;
*val1 = 3; // OK

let val2 = &2;
*val2 = 3; // error: cannot assign to immutable borrowed content
```

Note that `&mut` only makes sense with a reference - `foo: mut T` is not valid syntax. You can also combine the two qualifiers (`let mut a: &mut T`), when it makes sense.

Comment: I see. I guess it's like in C++ where you can have `int const*` vs. `int *const` to achieve different things.

Comment: @Shepmaster You might want to add that `mut` on a binding allows you to mutate inside the structure (if it is a struct).

Comment: I guess it stands out to me why rust doesn't seem to allow the syntax `let foo: mut Type`? It seems that since we already have the inevitable `& mut` in which `mut` can't appear on the left hand side, it's more uniform to say that `mut` can only appear on the right hand side?

Comment: @ScottOlson, can you please elaborate or point me to a source to explain the `mut` binding before a structure?

Comment: @BeyondSora Don't think of `&mut Type` as `&(mut Type)`, but as `(&mut) Type`. The keyword `mut` isn't used in types in general, but there is a type of reference called `&mut`.

Comment: @BeyondSora You can see the latest edit of the above answer. The basic explanation is when you can mutate a structure, you can mutate as far into the structure as you want (its fields, its fields' fields, etc). There are no `const` fields. This is safe since Rust guarantees when you can mutate something, no one else can read or mutate it at the same time.

Comment: @ScottOlson So, what you're saying is that `&mut` is just a "convenient" notation to avoid introducing a new keyword, but actually it is a different concept from the lhs usual `mut` keyword ?

Comment: @didierc Yeah. You can think of `&T` and `&mut T` as sugar for `Ref<T>` and `RefMut<T>` (types I just made up).

Comment: Although the technical name of a `&mut` is a pattern, I suggest to consider `&`, `&mut` as keywords or tokens at the beginning, which has nothing to do with the key word `mut`, to make it less confused.

Answer (score 178):

If you're coming from C/C++, it might also be helpful to think of it basically like this:

```
// Rust          C/C++
    a: &T     == const T* const a; // can't mutate either
mut a: &T     == const T* a;       // can't mutate what is pointed to
    a: &mut T == T* const a;       // can't mutate pointer
mut a: &mut T == T* a;             // can mutate both
```

You'll notice that these are inverses of each other. C/C++ take a "blacklist" approach, where if you want something to be immutable you have to say so explicitly, while Rust takes a "whitelist" approach, where if you want something to be mutable you have to say so explicitly.

Comment: This is a great table. It may be worthwhile to note that `&mut T` references are also analogous to `T* restrict` pointers in C: they may not be aliased. `&T` references have no such constraint and there is no reference type analogous to non-`restrict`-qualified `T*` pointers.

Comment: I don't have a C background, but I still think this explains it better (with the comments) as opposed to the accepted answer, sometimes simpler is better than longer.

Comment: [For people who forgot about C/C++ rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143272/3924118)

Answer (score 40):

The following natural language translation seems to clear things up for me...

```
let x = value;
  x {binds immutably} to {immutable value}

let mut x = value;
  x {binds mutably} to {possibly mutable value}

let x = &value;
  x {binds immutably} to {a reference to} {immutable value}

let x = &mut value;
  x {binds immutably} to {a reference to} {mutable value}

let mut x = &value;
  x {binds mutably} to {a reference to} {immutable value}

let mut x = &mut value;
  x {binds mutably} to {a reference to} {mutable value}
```

where

- `{binds mutably}` means the binding can be reassigned
- `{mutable value}` means the value's contents can change
- To be able to **mutate** a value you need both a *mutable binding* and a *mutable value*

Note:

*Reference mutability vs target mutability*

A reference variable such as `x`, as in `let x = &mut y`, is a separate variable from the target variable `y` it is pointing to. In particular, `x` has its own location on the stack and mutability permissions. As such, if `x` is immutable, as it is here, then it cannot be reassigned to point to some other variable. That restriction is separate from the ability to mutate the target through it, as in `*x = some_value`; the target is a distinct variable with its own mutability permissions.  However, if `w` is mutable, as in `let mut w = &mut p`, then it can indeed be reassigned to point to some other similarly typed variable: `w = &mut z`.

Comment: Are you sure about the statement "To be able to mutate a value you need both a mutable binding and a mutable value"? The following works for me
`
    fn main() {
        let mut value = 4;
        println!("{}", value);
        let x = &mut value;
        println!("{}", x);
        *x = 5;
        println!("{}", x);
    }
`

Comment: `value` is a location. The location contents is mutable. It currently contains `4`. `x` is a location on the stack. The location contents is immutable. It currently contains the address to `value`. The address type allows for mutation of that location contents. Consequently, though you cannot change `x` you can change what it refers to `*x`. These constraints are imposed at compile time in `safe rust` preventing certain code, in particular, the variable `value` will be unavailable while `x` has a mutable reference to it: there can only be one mutable reference to a variable at a time.

Comment: But $x$ is not a mutable binding is my point.

Comment: I see your point.

A reference is not a binding to the target. A reference is a separate variable that has its own mutability permissions. Specifically, `let x = &mut y` creates `x` as an immutable pointer variable located on the stack and containing the address to the variable `y` where, in this case, that location is mutable. On the other hand, `let mut x = &mut y` is a mutable pointer. In particular, the reassignment, `x = &mut z`, is now possible whereas before it is not.

Answer (score 1):

### Mutable Variable of Reference Type

When you have

```rust
let mut x: &T = value;
```

This means that `x` is variable that *refers to* an instance of `T`, as if by storing the memory address of the `T` instance in `x`'s value. This *reference* (i.e. the "memory address") is the subject of mutability in this context: `x` can be modified to refer to a different instance of `T` like this:

```rust
x = some_other_T_instance;
```

but the *referant* (i.e. the value of the `T` instance to which `x` refers) cannot be changed via `x`:

```rust
// Illegal
*x = a_different_value;
```

### Immutable variable of Mutable Reference type

When you have

```rust
let x: &mut T = value;
```

This means that `x` is a variable that refers to a mutable instance of `T`. In this case, the *referent* (i.e. the actual value) is the subject of mutability. It can be modified through the reference like this

```rust
*x = some_other_value;
```

but the reference itself (i.e. the "memory address" in the variable `x`) cannot:

```rust
// illegal
x = a_different_value;
```