# What is the difference between `&mut` on the type and the ident in a function signature?

Tags: rust

In a library I'm writing to understand Rust I created a trait Decodeable.

```
pub trait Decodeable {
    fn read_and_decode(&mut types::ReadSeeker) -> Result<Self, ::error::Error>;
}
```

I then implemented the type:

```
impl Decodeable for u32 {
    fn read_and_decode(&mut stream: types::ReadSeeker) -> Result<u32, error::Error> {
        try!(stream.big_edian_read_u32());
    }
}
```

This was failing with an error of:

```
error: method `read_and_decode` has an incompatible type for trait:
 expected &-ptr,
    found trait types::ReadSeeker
```

I eventually figured out if I change the function signature to `read_and_decode(stream: &mut types::ReadSeeker)`, it worked.

I'd like to understand what the difference between `&mut stream: types::ReadSeeker` and `stream: &mut types::ReadSeeker`. This feels like it is a fundamental part of rust, but I don't have any grasp on what the difference is beyond the fact that they are in fact different.

Answer (score 2):

`&mut x: T` is not valid, unless `T` is a `&mut U`.

```
fn foo(&mut a: i32) {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

gives this error:

```
<anon>:1:8: 1:14 error: mismatched types:
 expected `i32`,
    found `&mut _`
(expected i32,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
<anon>:1 fn foo(&mut a: i32) {
                ^~~~~~
```

However, the following function is valid:

```
fn foo(&mut a: &mut i32) {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

What `&mut x: &mut U` means is, *given a value of type `&mut U`, destructure the `&mut U` by dereferencing it and assign the result to `x`* (this is only valid if `U` implements `Copy`, otherwise you'll get a "cannot move out of borrowed content" error). In this situation, `&mut x` is a [*pattern*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/patterns.html). You also find patterns in `let` statements and in `match` arms, and the meaning is always the same.

```
fn foo(a: &mut i32) {
    let &mut b = a;
    match a {
        &mut c => unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

In practice, we rarely write something like `&mut a: &mut T` in a function signature.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I happened to also find  [28587698](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-in-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the?rq=1) which this is a duplicate of so I'm going to close the question.