# How can I do a mutable borrow in a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, rust, mutable, borrow-checker

I tried:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec = [1, 2, 3];
    
    for mut x in &vec { *x = 3; }
    for mut &x in &vec { x = 3; }
    for mut *x in &vec { x = 3; }
    for mut x in mut &vec { *x = 3; }
    for mut x in &(mut vec) { *x = 3; }
}
```

None of these work; how should I do it?

I get errors like:

> - `mut` must be attached to each individual binding
> - expected identifier, found `*`
> - expected expression, found keyword `mut`
> - cannot assign to `*x` which is behind a `&` reference

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You may want to re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), specifically the sections on:

- [mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html)
- [mutable references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references)
- [vectors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch08-01-vectors.html)

> We can also iterate over mutable references to each element in a mutable vector in order to make changes to all the elements. The `for` loop in Listing 8-9 will add `50` to each element.
>
> ```rust
> let mut v = vec![100, 32, 57];
> for i in &mut v {
>     *i += 50;
> }
> ```
>
> Listing 8-9: Iterating over mutable references to elements in a vector
>
> To change the value that the mutable reference refers to, we have to use the dereference operator (`*`) to get to the value in `i` before we can use the `+=` operator.

In addition, you can call the [`iter_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter_mut) method:

```rust
let mut v = vec![100, 32, 57];
for i in v.iter_mut() {
    *i += 50;
}
```

See also:

- [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/155423)
- [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423)

---

Note that your variable is **not a vector**. It is an array.

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed the no bracket version for `for mut x in &(mut vec)`

Comment: If you already have a mutable slice like `v: &mut [u32]` as a function arg, `for i in v { *i += 50; }` works the same as `v.iter_mut()`.  (I don't know if there's any subtle difference, but it compiled the same way.)

Comment: I undertand what mutability is, I don't understand why a variable should be mutable as a loop argument, when it's actually immutable (read: not changed, only read).

Comment: @flm mutability in Rust is hierarchical — in order to change a value inside the `Vec` you also need to be able to change the `Vec` itself. The compiler doesn't know / expose to the user the fact that changing one element of a `Vec` doesn't require changing the data of the `Vec` itself.

Comment: @Shepmaster, okay I see. `i` - is an array item and it changed inside the loop, that's why original array `v` marked as mutable, because its value is changed inside this loop.