# How can I mutate the contents of an optional Vec?

Tags: rust, option-type, egui

I'm trying to learn rust with egui, and I'm trying to make a list of checkboxes.

```
struct Checkbox {
    check: bool,
    text: String
}
```

Eventually, the borrow checker doesn't like this code:

```
// There is a parameter &mut self
// self.header: Option<Vec<Checkbox>>
if let Some(header) = &self.header {
    for i in 0..header.len() - 1 {
        ui.checkbox(&mut header[i].check, header[i].text);
    }
}
```

The compiler says `cannot borrow '*header' as mutable, as it is behind a '&' reference` in the for loop (ui.checkbox line), which kind of makes sense, but I'm not sure what the workaround is. I get the same error if I use `for head in header.into_iter() {`. And, of course, I tried using `let Some(header) = self.header`, but that gives `cannot move out of 'self.header.0' which is behind a mutable reference`.

Comment: From the error I understand self is already borrowed mutable, you cannot use 
`into_iter` since it will try to change the ownership of the `vec`, looks like you don't really need an ownership, instead you can use `iter_mut` to get items as mutable:  `header.iter_mut().for_each(|item |ui.checkbox(item.check, item.text))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do a mutable borrow in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622783/how-can-i-do-a-mutable-borrow-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to borrow it mutably:

```
let Some(header) = &mut self.header
```

Comment: I feel silly for not figuring that out.