# Why can I not use `+=` on a mutable reference?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I want to apply `+=` to a mutable reference (`&mut`), but I do not understand why it does not compile:

```
use std::ops::AddAssign;

struct Num {
    value: usize,
}

impl AddAssign for Num {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, other: Num) {
        self.value += other.value;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut n1 = Num { value: 42 };
    let n2 = Num { value: 41 };
    n1 += n2; // It work!

    let ref mut rn1 = n1; // Get &mut Num
    let n2 = Num { value: 41 };
    rn1 += n2; // It could not be compiled !
}
```

I think `&mut Num += Num` is valid because `add_assign` takes `&mut self`.

But the compiler error is:

```
error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `&mut Num`
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
20 |    rn1 += n2;
   |    ^^^ cannot use '+=' on type '&mut Num'
```

Comment: Specifically, you need `impl<'a> AddAssign<Num> for &'a mut Num {` and then `let mut rn1 = &mut n1;`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there difference between `let ref mut rn1 = n1;` and `let mut rn1 = &mut n1` ?

Comment: Yes. One produces a mutable reference (`rn1: &mut Foo`), the other produces a mutable mutable reference (`mut rn1: &mut Foo`). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/155423. Said more concisely, one works here, the other doesn't. Also `let mut ref x = foo`, while valid, is not idiomatic; `let x = &mut foo`  is.