# How can a function argument allow mutating a variable but not be capable of pointing to any other variable?

Tags: reference, rust, immutability, mutable

I want a function that calls other functions that are mutually recursive, but I already have that with type signatures like:

```
fn f1(mut index: &mut usize, ..)
fn f2(mut index: &mut usize, ..)
```

I really want a set of mutually recursive functions that can only mutate the  `index` variable I've defined in my `main()` function, and are **not capable** of pointing to any other variable.

I've read the 2 answers from [What's the difference in `mut` before a variable name and after the `:`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-in-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the), and I've tried several approaches but still I can't achieve what I want. I think I don't really understand the concepts.

Here is evidence of my current understanding:

```
// with &mut I can change the referred value of n, but then I can't
// pass a mutable reference anywhere
fn mutate_usize_again(n: &mut usize) {
    *n += 1;
    // n += 70; ^ cannot use `+=` on type `&mut usize`
}

fn mutate_usize_two_times(mut n: &mut usize) {
    *n = 8;
    // if I don't write mut n, I can't pass a mutable reference to
    // the mutate_usize_again function
    mutate_usize_again(&mut n);
}

fn mutate_usize_one_time_referred_value(n: &mut usize) {
    *n += 25;
}

// this changes the referred value of n
fn mutate_usize_one_time_mutable_pointer(mut n: usize) {
    println!("n before assigning in mutate_usize_one_time = {}", n);
    n = 48;
    println!("n after assigning in mutate_usize_one_time = {}", n);
}

// doesn't work because of lifetimes
// this changes where is pointing a (Copy?) reference of n
// passed value does not change
/*
fn mutate_usize_one_time(mut n: &usize) {
    println!("n before assigning in mutate_usize_one_time = {}", n);
    n = &48;
    println!("n after assigning in mutate_usize_one_time = {}", n);
}
*/

fn main() {
    let mut index = 0;
    mutate_usize_one_time_mutable_pointer(index);
    println!("index after mutate_usize_one_time_mutable_pointer = {}", index);
    mutate_usize_two_times(&mut index);
    println!("index after mutate_usize_two_times = {}", index);
    mutate_usize_one_time_referred_value(&mut index);
    println!("index after mutate_usize_ = {}", index);
}
```

I would really appreciate a nice explanation of what is going on in my code if I've misunderstood.

I'm starting to think that what I want is already done given:

1. `index` must refer to its updated value => `mut index`
2. `index` must be capable of changing the referred value and pass mutable references to the other functions. => `&mut usize`
3. If it were another function parameter with the same type `(mut index2: &mut usize)`, the compiler would not let me have 2 mutable references pointing to the same memory location.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Modify the value that the reference point to or change the reference itself?

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi edited with more complete information about my goals

Comment: @freinn I guess you are still confused. Concentrate, by then try to recall your thoughts and dig into them. Before you understand a code you shall be able to guess what it does in a first glance. We can't help you always, but we can guess. From you write we see what think and where you think.

Comment: @VitaliPom question == question => not knowing. answer == answer => knowledge is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference is a variable that points to something else. References do not collapse, so in Rust you can have a reference to a reference.

Your linked question describes what's different between `x: &mut T` and `mut x: T`. `mut x: &T` means you can change where the reference points to, but you can't change the value what it points to.

Non-reference values will be copied when passed to functions (or moved, if not implementing `Copy`).

A working example:

```
// with &mut I can change the referred value of n
fn mutate_usize_again(n: &mut usize) {
    *n += 1;
    *n += 70;
}

fn mutate_usize_two_times(n: &mut usize) {
    *n = 8;
    // just pass it along
    mutate_usize_again(n);
}

fn mutate_usize_one_time_referred_value(n: &mut usize) {
    *n += 25;
}

// this changes the **local** value of n
fn mutate_usize_one_time_mutable_pointer(mut n: usize) {
    println!("n before assigning in mutate_usize_one_time = {}", n);
    n = 48;
    println!("n after assigning in mutate_usize_one_time = {}", n);
}

fn main() {
    let mut index = 0;
    mutate_usize_one_time_mutable_pointer(index);
    println!("index after mutate_usize_one_time_mutable_pointer = {}", index);
    mutate_usize_two_times(&mut index);
    println!("index after mutate_usize_two_times = {}", index);
    mutate_usize_one_time_referred_value(&mut index);
    println!("index after mutate_usize_one_time_referred_value = {}", index);
}
```

Comment: nice answer, but I think my first 2 code comments are wrong and are still in your answer.

Comment: Removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

*Ah! The old pointer/pointee issue. Don't worry, it's a common stumbling block. Keep at it, at some point it'll click and then it'll just seem obvious.*

**What is a reference?**

A reference is an indirection. The address of a thing that exists somewhere else.

Let's use an analogy:

- a function *frame* is a closet, with lots of drawers,
- each drawer may contain one value.

For the moment, let's forget about *types*, *stack* and *heap*: we only have closets and drawers:

- a *value* is in a drawer, it may moved or copied to another drawer,
- a *reference* is the address of this value, represented as a pair of IDs (closet ID, drawer ID).

*Note: it is nonsensical to mention just a drawer ID, all closets have a drawer 0...*

---

**How to use a drawer?**

Let us imagine a (typeless) simple example, the addition function:

```
fn add(left, right) { left + right }
```

Now, what happens when we call `add(3, 4)`?

```
Function
  call

+-add-+  <-- New closet
|  3  |  <-- Drawer 0: value 3
+-----+
|  4  |  <-- Drawer 1: value 4
+-----+
```

*Note: in the following, I'll represent a closet as an array. This closet would be `[3, 4]`. I'll also "number" the closets using letters, to avoid mixing closets and drawers, so this closet could be `d`, and the first drawer of `d` would be `0@d` (which contains 3 here).*

The function is defined as "take the value in drawer 0, take the value in drawer 1, add them together in drawer 2, return content of drawer 2".

Let's spice things up; and introduce references:

```
fn modify() {
    let x = 42;
    let y = &x;
    *y = 32;
}
```

What does `modify` do?

- call `modify` => a fresh closet is given to us `a: []`,
- `let x = 42;` => our closet is now `a: [42]`,
- `let y = &x;` => our closet is now `a: [42, 0@a]`,

And now comes the crux: `*y = 32;`. This means put 32 in the drawer pointed to by `y`. And thus the closet is now: `a: [32, 0@a]`.

---

**Your first example**

Let's look at your first example, put in situation with a `main`:

```
// with &mut I can change the referred value of n, but then I can't
// pass a mutable reference anywhere
fn mutate_usize_again(n: &mut usize) {
    *n += 1;
    // n += 70; ^ cannot use `+=` on type `&mut usize`
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 24;
    mutate_usize_gain(&mut x);
}
```

So, what's going on here?

- call `main` => a fresh closet is allocated `a: []`,
- `let mut x = 24;` => `a: [24]`,
- call `mutate_usize_again` => a fresh closet allocated `b: []`,
- with `&mut x` => `b: [0@a]`,
- `*n += 1;` => add 1 to the drawer pointed to by `n` (0@a), this means that `b` does not change, but `a` does! Now `a: [25]`.
- `n += 70` => add 70 to a reference... this does not make sense, a reference does not have arithmetic operations.

---

**Your second example**

Let's move on to your second example, augmented:

```
// Parameter renamed because it's confusing to always use the same letter
fn mutate_usize_again(z: &mut usize) { *z += 1; }

fn mutate_usize_two_times(mut n: &mut usize) {
    *n = 8;
    // if I don't write mut n, I can't pass a mutable reference to
    // the mutate_usize_again function
    mutate_usize_again(&mut n);
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 24;
    mutate_usize_two_times(&mut x);
}
```

We'll need 3 closets!

- call `main` => a fresh closet is allocated `a: []`,
- `let mut x = 24` => `a: [24]`,
- call `mutate_usize_two_times` => a fresh closet is allocated `b: []`,
- with `n: &mut usize = &mut x` => `b: [0@a]`,
- `*n = 8` => stores 8 in the drawer pointed to by `n`: `a: [8]`, `b` unchanged,
- call `mutate_usize_again` => a fresh closet is allocated `c: []`,
- with `z: &mut usize = &mut n` => ERROR. The type of `&mut n` is `&mut &mut usize` which cannot be assigned to a parameter of type `z`,
- let's pretend you used `z: &mut usize = n` => `c: [0@a]`,
- `*z += 1` => adds 1 to the value in the drawer pointed to by `z`: `a: [9]`, `b` and `c` unchanged.

You can take a reference to a reference, but it's not what you meant to do here. We can indeed twist the example to making it work though by defining:

```
 fn mutate_usize_again(z: &mut &mut usize) { **z += 1; }
                          ^                   ^~~ dereference TWICE
                          |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ two levels of reference
```

In this case, starting again from the call to `mutate_usize_again`:

- before call, we had: `a: [8]`, `b: [0@a]`
- call `mutate_usize_again` => a fresh closet is allocated `c: []`,
- with `z: &mut &mut usize = &mut n` => `c: [0@b]` <- a reference to a reference!
- `**z += 1` => adds 1 to the value in drawer pointed to by the reference pointed to by `z`. `**z += 1` is `**0@b += 1` which is `*0@a += 1`, which modifies `a` to be `a: [9]` and leaves `b` and `c` unchanged.

---

**Your third example**

Your third example, enhanced:

```
fn mutate_usize_one_time_mutable_pointer(mut n: usize) {
    println!("n before assigning in mutate_usize_one_time = {}", n);
    n = 48;
    println!("n after assigning in mutate_usize_one_time = {}", n);
}

fn main() {
    let x = 42;
    mutate_usize_one_time_mutable_pointer(x);
}
```

Let's go:

- call `main` => a fresh closet is allocated `a: []`,
- `let x = 42;` => `a: [42]`,
- call `mutate_usize_one_time_mutable_pointer` => a fresh closet is allocated `b: []`
- with `n: mut usize = x` => `b: [42]`,
- `n = 48` => modifies the value of `n`: `b: [48]`, *note that `a` is unchanged*
- end of `mutate_usize_one_time_mutable_pointer`, discards `b`, `a: [42]`.

There is no pointer involved here, the name of the function is misleading.

---

**Your final example**

Your fourth example, augmented:

```
fn mutate_usize_one_time(mut n: &usize) {
    println!("n before assigning in mutate_usize_one_time = {}", n);
    n = &48;
    println!("n after assigning in mutate_usize_one_time = {}", n);
}

fn main() {
    let x = 42;
    mutate_usize_one_time(&x);
}
```

Let's go:

- call `main` => a fresh closet is allocated `a: []`,
- `let x = 42;` => `a: [42]`,
- call `mutate_usize_one_time` => a fresh closet is allocated `b: []`,
- `n: &size = &x` => `b: [0@a]`,
- `48` => `b: [0@a, 48]`
- `&48` => `b: [0@a, 48, 1@b]`
- `n = &48` => would lead to `b: [1@b, 48]` however lifetimes forbid references pointing to something *past* them, this is forbidden.

---

Hope it's starting making sense. If not... then go for a run, go out with friends, clear your head, read another explanation, clear your head again, and come back again. It'll seep in little by little ;)

Answer (score -5):

Considering your title, you're confused on the very principle.
Short answer that strikes it all:

> You shall always follow the even rule. You have same amount of slashes and same amount of dereferences. Together they give an even number.

Comment: Yayyyy glad to help ^^

Comment: A slash is `/` (and a backslash is ``\``). What symbol do you actually mean?

Comment: @Shepmaster backslash

Comment: That leaves me even more confused. There are no backslashes *anywhere* in this code. I really don't know what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Shepmaster I just tried to dig into the editor's head. He was asking how pointers work. Before my comment, unless I confuse the Q, he verified and later deleted his comment, about my answer - that I hit his thoughts.

Comment: My point is that the backslash symbol (``\``) has *nothing to do* with pointers. I still don't know why you brought it up in the first place.

Comment: Ooooh oh ooooh sorry. I'm mistaken with the other slash. Thanks for correcting :)

Comment: I truly apologize, as I don't think I'm doing a good job of communicating. **Neither** slash (`/`) nor backslash (``\``) have anything to do with pointers.

Comment: In physics I think, there is a reference - "Even mistake is a truth sentence". He was asking about references and I answered in his language :D with backslash instead of slash.... it's psychological mistake :)))))) it's truth, he confirmed/

Comment: @Shepmaster speak in the language children speak, they'll get you. Others not.

Comment: Please understand that answers are also made to be understood by other people who stumble upon the same or similar problems. As it is, this answer is of poor quality and hardly makes any sense to the wider Rust programming community. In fact, nothing so far even shows that the OP understands it.

Comment: @E_net4 They deleted my comment because this is not a good answer. I only tried to be grateful. The only thing he's saying is that it must be an even number of & and *, like in C++ etc. But he is confusing character's names or thinking in another language.

Comment: yeah I know, they have their own distinctions in their heads :) it's what I thought for the first time. It's okay, I hope it gave you boost. Good luck in the next steps :)) @freinn

Comment: @E_net4 there are 80% of children or new scholars who learn how to code here, we have a different language of speaking before reaching the point that "Pointer" and "Reference" are two different tings. let us, it will be rewarded in the end for your. 80% of the users here are going to made 4x working power in the next 10 years for the market and double the working power already in the next 2 years. Consider us as the people who write the next gen. of tools for you, we can also revenge you back ;) but you're okay. I'm glad people started to arise attention on those important topics.