# Immutable object changing to mutable depending on function signature

Tags: rust, immutability, move-semantics, borrow-checker

Checkout the Rust code below. It compiles

```
fn main() {
    let vec0 = Vec::new();

    let mut vec1 = fill_vec(vec0);

    println!("{} has length {} content `{:?}`", "vec1", vec1.len(), vec1);

    vec1.push(88);

    println!("{} has length {} content `{:?}`", "vec1", vec1.len(), vec1);
}

fn fill_vec(mut vec: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    vec.push(22);
    vec.push(44);
    vec.push(66);

    vec
}
```

Here I am declaring `vec0` as `immutable` but `fill_vec` takes in a mutable vector. Depending on the function signature it seems Rust is changing the nature of the argument being passed.

My question is, this obviously seems like a "shot yourself in the foot" instant. Why does Rust allow this? Or, is this actually safe and I am missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the compiler not complain that an iterator moved to a for loop is immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760006/why-does-the-compiler-not-complain-that-an-iterator-moved-to-a-for-loop-is-immut)

Comment: @E_net4isadownvote this question seems a bit more general that the linked duplicate candidate.

Answer (score 4):

There are different things at play here that can all explain why this behavior make sense:

- First of, `mut` doesn't *really* mean "mutable". There are such things as interior mutability, `Cell`s, `Mutex`es, etc., which allow you to modify state without needing a single `mut`. Rather, `mut` means that you can get *mutually* exclusive references.
- Second, mutability is a property of a binding. `vec0` in `main` and `vec` in `fill_vec` are different bindings, so they can have different mutability.

  See also:

  - [What does 'let x = x' do in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595345/what-does-let-x-x-do-in-rust)
- Finally ownership: `fill_vec` takes full ownership of its parameter, which effectively doesn't exist anymore in `main`. Why should the function not be allowed to do whatever it wants with its owned parameters? Had the function taken the parameter as a mutable reference, you would have needed to declare the original binding as `mut`:

  ```rust
  fn main() {
      let mut vec0 = Vec::new();
      //  ^^^ now _needs_ a mutable binding

      fill_vec(&mut vec0);
      //       ^^^^ needs an explicit `&mut` reference
  }

  fn fill_vec(vec: &mut Vec<i32>) {
      //           ^^^^ borrows rather than take ownership
      // …
  }
  ```

Comment: In basic terms; if you hand over the ownership of something the new owner has rights to do anything with that(even destroying), if you have concerns then you have to lend it to proper target with a rules.

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're making the argument `vec` of `fill_vec` mutable. You are still passing the vec by value.

If you wanted a mutable reference you would have `vec: &mut Vec<i32>`.