# Why immutable string can call String::add(mut self, other: &str)

Tags: rust, move-semantics

In **stdlib**
string.rs:

```
impl Add<&str> for String {
    type Output = String;

    #[inline]
    fn add(mut self, other: &str) -> String {
        self.push_str(other);
        self
    }
}


let s1 = String::from("tic");
let s2 = String::from("tac");

let s = s1 + &s2;// it works
```

**s1** is immutable here, but Add::add(**mut self**, other: &str) is mut, I just want to know why.

Comment: AFAIK, `mut self` is different from `&mut self`, and your variable would have to be mutable only in the second case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You borrow and consume `s1` when you use it in the concatenation. If you try to print `s1` after the line
`let s = s1 + &s2;// it works`,
there will be an error because it is used after move:

```
3 |     let s1 = String::from("tic");
  |         -- move occurs because `s1` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
6 |     let s = s1 + &s2;// it works
  |             -- value moved here
7 |     println!("{}{}{}",s,s1,s2);
  |                         ^^ value borrowed here after move
```

`s1` does not need to be mutable as the variable is never mutated the data is moved and mutated to the variable `s`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> s1 is immutable here
> ```

Not exactly. The `s1` binding is immutable, but since `add` *takes ownership* of the value it was bound to, it can do what it wants with it (including mutating it). As you don't have access to the value anymore you can't observe changes and it makes no difference to you.

It's not dissimilar to the meatworld: if you *lend* something to somebody and they have your permission to modify it then they might do so, but if you *give* something to somebody, whether they modify it is none of your business anymore.

As Simson notes, if you try to reuse `s1` after the addition the compiler will reject your code.