# what is the difference between String::from and mut x = "some string" in rust

Tags: string, rust, heap-memory, stack-memory

my understanding is that declaring a string variable like the following

```
let x = "a string"
```

allocates memory for immutable x on the stack

while declaring x like this

```
let x = String::from("a string");
```

does the same but on the heap. And this way we create a mutable string variable.

My question is this, is there any difference between the following:

```
let mut x = "a string";
```

and

```
let x = String::from("a string");
```

doesn't this mean that in both cases x is a mutable string variable?
can I assign x to another variable as in `"y = x"`?

Comment: my question is a little different

Comment: @krabbos Your question is phrased a bit differently, but the answer is: _one creates a `String` and the other creates a `&'static str`_. Which then leaves the question: _what's the difference?_

Comment: Shades of [What's the difference between placing “mut” before a variable name and after the “:”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/3650362). `let mut x = "a string"` doesn't make `x` a `&'static mut str`

Comment: Note: duplicate don't mean the same question but the same answer...

Comment: `let mut x = "a string";`

declares a mutable variable that holds a borrow to immutable content `&str`. For example, the following will compile:

    `let mut x = "a string"; x = "hi";`

However, if you remove the `mut` you will get the error

"cannot assign twice to immutable variable `x`"

The type `&mut str` needs to have something with a mutable backing like `String`. For example notice that in the docs https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html all methods that take `&mut self` have examples using `String`.