# Why the error: error[E0614]: type `str` cannot be dereferenced

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm very new to Rust, so this most probably a stupid question to ask.

I've couple of questions.

I've these two functions:

```
fn modifier2(mut ptr: Box<String>) -> Box<String> {
    println!("In modifier2...");
    println!("Ptr points to {:p}, and value is {}", ptr, *ptr);

    *ptr = ptr.to_uppercase();

    println!("Exit modifier2...");
    ptr
}

fn modifier3(ptr: &mut Box<String>)  {

    println!("In modifier3...");
    println!("Ptr points to {:p}, and value is {}", ptr, *ptr);
    println!("Ptr points to {:p}, and value is {}", *ptr, **ptr);

    **ptr = "another".to_uppercase();

    //**ptr = **ptr.to_uppercase(); //error[E0614]: type `str` cannot be dereferenced

    println!("Exit modifier3...");
}
```

And I'm calling them like this:

```
let mut answer = Box::new("Hello World".to_string());    
answer = modifier2(answer);
println!("called modifier2(): {} length: {}", answer, answer.len());

let mut answer = Box::new("Hello World".to_string());    
modifier3(&mut answer);
println!("called modifier3(): {} length: {}", answer, answer.len());
```

This results the following, which looks fine to me:

```
In modifier2...
Ptr points to 0x2145fa1d990, and value is Hello World
Exit modifier2...
called modifier2(): HELLO WORLD length: 11

In modifier3...
Ptr points to 0x50426ffb60, and value is Hello World
Ptr points to 0x2145fa1dc50, and value is Hello World
Exit modifier3...
called modifier3(): ANOTHER length: 7
```

I've two questions:

1) In fn modifier2(mut ptr: Box) -> Box , what is the significance of making the ptr as mute? How it differs from fn modifier2(ptr: mut Box) -> Box ?

2) In the commented line in fn modifier3, i.e., **ptr = **ptr.to_uppercase();, results in an error "error[E0614]: type `str` cannot be dereferenced", while I can do the same uppercase() in fn modifier2?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
If I change modifier3() like this:

```
fn modifier3(&mut ptr: &mut Box<String>)  {

    println!("In modifier3...");
    println!("Ptr points to {:p}, and *PTR points to {}, and value is {}", ptr, *ptr, **ptr);

    *ptr = "another".to_uppercase(); //or **ptr = *"another".to_uppercase();   

    println!("Exit modifier3...");
}
```

It gives the following errors:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src\main.rs:99:5
    |
99  |     println!("Ptr points to {:p}, and *PTR points to {}, and value is {}", ptr, *ptr, **ptr);
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

A little confused here with the usage of &mut ptr.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-between-placing-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the), so I'll keep things short. Effectively, it means that the function takes a `Box<String>` by value and binds it to a mutable variable. It's the same as simply doing `let mut ptr = ptr` on the first line of the function. It's very different from taking an argument by mutable *reference*. Here, we own the `Box<String>`, so in particular we can change it if we wish.

---

When you call a method on an object, the Rust compiler will perform what's known as "autoderef" to figure out exactly what method to call. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) for some more information on that. In effect, it allows us to call methods on an object behind a reference or some other kind of pointer.

That's what's happening with `**ptr.to_uppercase()`. `ptr` is autoderef'd to a `str`, and then a new `String` gets produced by that method (see [the type signature on `to_uppercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_uppercase)).

Then, you try to deref this `String` twice. The first deref results in a `str`, but the second one fails with `` error[E0614]: type `str` cannot be dereferenced ``. You might be confusing the order of operations here. `**ptr.to_uppercase()` performs `to_uppercase`, then derefs. To change the order, use `(**ptr).to_uppercase()` (this actually works here, but is unidiomatic because autoderef does that kind of thing for you).

To fix the code, simply remove the derefs on that line.

```
fn modifier2(mut ptr: Box<String>) -> Box<String> {
    println!("In modifier2...");
    println!("Ptr points to {:p}, and value is {}", ptr, *ptr);

    *ptr = ptr.to_uppercase();

    println!("Exit modifier2...");
    ptr
}

fn modifier3(ptr: &mut Box<String>) {
    println!("In modifier3...");
    println!("Ptr points to {:p}, and value is {}", ptr, *ptr);
    println!("Ptr points to {:p}, and value is {}", *ptr, **ptr);

    **ptr = "another".to_uppercase();

    **ptr = ptr.to_uppercase(); // No error now

    println!("Exit modifier3...");
}

fn main() {
    let mut answer = Box::new("Hello World".to_string());
    answer = modifier2(answer);
    println!("called modifier2(): {} length: {}", answer, answer.len());

    let mut answer = Box::new("Hello World".to_string());
    modifier3(&mut answer);
    println!("called modifier3(): {} length: {}", answer, answer.len());
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c3aa153e41b724c3e5a450c37c27b14b)

The code has one Clippy warning. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o) from some tips.