# How can I pass mutable Vec<Something> variable to function and get item that is indexed

Tags: vector, rust

When I try the code below for the `Vec<Ev>` I get a [[E0308]: mismatched type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0308) error.

```
use std::fmt::Error;
#[derive(Debug)]

struct Ev {
    semt: String,
    fiyat : i32,
}

impl Ev {
    fn yeni (alan: &str,fiyat: i32) -> Ev {
        Self {
            semt: alan.to_string(),
            fiyat
        }
    }
}


fn dizi_yap(boyut:usize) -> Result<Vec<Ev>,Error> {
    let mut evler = Vec::<Ev>::with_capacity(boyut);
    evler.push(Ev::yeni("melikgazi", 210));
    evler.push(Ev::yeni("kocasinan", 120));
    evler.push(Ev::yeni("hacılar", 410));
    evler.push(Ev::yeni("bünyan", 90));
    Ok(evler)
}

fn elemani_getir(&mut dizi:Vec<Ev>, sira:usize) -> Ev {
    dizi[sira]
    // dizi.get(sira).expect("hata")
}


fn main() {

    let mut dizi = dizi_yap(1).expect("ulasmadi");

    println!("eleman: {:?}",dizi[3]);
    println!("eleman: {:?}",elemani_getir(dizi, 3))

}
```

How can I get Vec indexed item in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in you function arguments is a little off. Mutable arguments can be a little confusing, as there are two different representations. Refer to [this question for a more detailed explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-between-placing-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the)

Here is the `elemali_getit` function corrected:

```rust
fn elemani_getir(mut dizi: &Vec<Ev>, sira: usize) -> &Ev {
  &dizi[sira]
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```rust
println!("eleman: {:?}", elemani_getir(&dizi, 3))
```

Note that `elemani_getir` now returns a reference to `Ev` (`&Ev`). Returning `Ev` instead results in an error:

```rust
cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<Ev>`
```

To get around this error, you can either return a reference to `Ev` as shown above, or return an exact duplicated of `Ev` my deriving the `Clone` trait:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Ev {
  semt: String,
  fiyat: i32,
}

fn elemani_getir(mut dizi: &Vec<Ev>, sira: usize) -> Ev {
  dizi[sira].clone()
}
```

Comment: @natrollus No problem, happy to help