# fn taking FnMut closure in trait -> either "patterns aren't allowed in functions without bodies" or "please add mut"

Tags: types, rust, closures

```rust
pub struct A {}

pub trait FooTakesFnMut {
    fn foo<VF>(&self, mut fnmuti32: VF)
    where
        VF: FnMut(i32);
}

impl FooTakesFnMut for A {
    fn foo<VF>(&self, mut fnmuti32: VF)
    where
        VF: FnMut(i32),
    {
        for x in 1..5 {
            fnmuti32(x);
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn test_00() {
        let a = A;
        let mut v = Vec::new();
        let bar = |x| { v.push(x); };
        a.foo(bar);
        assert_eq!(v, vec![1,2,3,4]);
    }
}
```

[link to play rust playground copy](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=324bcb1ecef12c76179f5de48d3c6c0d)

Compiler complains:

```
error: patterns aren't allowed in functions without bodies
 --> src/lib.rs:9:23
  |
9 |     fn foo<VF>(&self, mut fnmuti32: VF)
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: remove `mut` from the parameter: `fnmuti32`
<--cut-->
```

but after removing `mut` from `foo` functions signatures , it suggests adding them :

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `fnmuti32` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:20:13
   |
15 |     fn foo<VF>(&self,  fnmuti32: VF)
   |                        -------- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut fnmuti32`
...
20 |             fnmuti32(x);
   |             ^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
<--cut-->
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-between-placing-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the)

Comment: Not at all, because in my case the issue of semantic difference between `trait` and implementation `impl`. And https://stackoverflow.com/a/67684589/544721 captured exactly problem in his point no .2 ,that's why I edited his answer to highlight answer no.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code and this should work:

```rust
pub struct A;

pub trait FooTakesFnMut {
    fn foo<VF>(&self, fnmuti32: VF)
    where
        VF: FnMut(i32);
}

impl FooTakesFnMut for A {
    fn foo<VF>(&self, mut fnmuti32: VF)
    where
        VF: FnMut(i32),
    {
        for x in 1..=5 {
            fnmuti32(x);
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
#[allow(unused_imports)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn test_00() {
        let a = A;
        let mut v = Vec::new();
        let bar = |x| { v.push(x); };
        a.foo(bar);
        assert_eq!(v, vec![1,2,3,4,5]);
    }
}
```

1. `struct A {}` is replaced with `struct A;` so that `A` could be used as the only instance value of the [ZST](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#zero-sized-types-zsts) `A` instead of `A {}`.
2. **The `mut` keyword attached to a parameter is only a matter of an implementation because as long as the ownership is transferred into the function, whether the implementation would mutate the argument is no longer decided by the caller.**
3. `1..5` is changed to `1..=5` so that the result would match the provided test case.

Comment: Please provide a citation for your point 1. `struct A {}` and `struct A` are both zero sized.

Comment: @Shepmaster I didn't mean that `struct A {}` is not zero sized. But there are ways to define a ZST. As a value is instantiate with `A`, the definition has to be `struct A;` so that it could compile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you specified the `mut` in the trait definition. The `mut` makes the variable binding mutable, this kind of information belongs in the trait implementation, not the declaration.

If you remove the `mut` on your trait definition, your code compiles.