# Why can I change a &mut str within main, but cannot pass it to another function to change the value?

Tags: string, rust, borrow-checker

This works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let mut mystr = "this is my string";
    println!("{}", mystr);
    mystr = "new string";
    println!("{}", mystr);
}
```

This does not work:

```rust
fn change(s: &mut str) {
    s = "new string";
    println!("{}", s);
}

fn main() {
    let mut mystr = "change me";
    //change(mystr);
    //change(&mystr);
    //change(&mut mystr);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     s = "new string";
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
  |
  = note: expected mutable reference `&mut str`
                     found reference `&'static str`
```

I don't know if I'm making a mistake or if the borrow checker is stopping it. The compiler errors don't really tell me.

I've tried the 3 different ways of passing the variable as the compiler error changes and sometimes says trying to pass `&str` to `&mut str` and when I change it to `&mut mystr` I get a new error.

Am I making a mistake or is this not allowed?

Comment: Does [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/155423) answer your question?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84aa41febf9be97ed2a41e3aae220970

Comment: Thanks for the example. ive been working through the examples on the try it yourself and i thought i had a basic grasp of the borrowing system but i must have missed this, i cant understand it either.  i dont know why i need  & before mut and &before str. I thought Variable = was a constant, &variable = reference to constant,  &mut variable = reference to a mutable   what is &mut &str   or have i just got confused becauise its &str for a slice, is  &mut &str just the same as &mut int  ?

Comment: Your last statement is exactly correct  - `&str` is a string slice, and `&mut &str` is just like `&mut AnyOtherType`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-between-placing-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the)

Answer (score 0):

I added the type to your first example to highlight what's happening.

```
fn main() {
    let mut mystr: &'static str = "this is my string";
    println!("{}", mystr);
    mystr = "new string";
    println!("{}", mystr);
}
```

Here's your second example.  I changed the type of the `s` argument and added a `*`.

```
fn change(s: &mut &'static str) {
    *s = "new string";
}

fn main() {
    let mut mystr = "change me";
    println!("{}", mystr);
    change(&mut mystr);
    println!("{}", mystr);
}
```