# Why does the Rust compiler accept a mutable value where it should've been immutable?

Tags: rust

I have a struct called `Layer` and a `save_as_ppm` function inside a impl block, the signature of the function is this:

```
fn save_as_ppm(&self, filename: &str){}
```

But other functions inside the impl block have `&mut self` parameter so when I create an instance I have to make it mutable (I don't know if it's called an instance in Rust).

```
let mut inputs = Layer::new(SAMPLE_SIZE as usize, SAMPLE_SIZE as usize);
```

But when I call this `save_as_ppm` function:

```
inputs.save_as_ppm(&filepath)
```

It compiles. My question is why does it compile? `save_as_ppm` takes a reference to `self` but I've just passed a mutable `self`. Shouldn't the compiler give an error? At least a warning?

Comment: The compiler is allowed to automatically cast `&mut T` to `&T`, just not the other way around.

Comment: Following the rules of duck typing, since a mutable reference has all the features + more compared to an immutable reference, I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to pass in a mutable reference since the function itself won't be able to mutate the state either way

Comment: A method that needs a shared reference will happily accept a mutable one, because it's always safe to "downgrade" a mutable reference to a shared one. It would indeed be annoying if `let mut v = vec![]; v.push(1); println!("{}", v.len())` wouldn't compile because `Vec::len()` takes `&self`, but `v` is mut.

Comment: Function won't be able to mutate the state because the signature is immutable? @Samathingamajig

Comment: Since Rust compiler is very pedantic I thought it wouldn't like this kind of casting at all

Comment: @merovingian Yeah the function won't be able to mutate the state since its signature is for an immutable reference. Trying to mutate the state will give a compiler error.

Comment: @merovingian Rust is generally pretty reserved on implicit coercions but [they do exist](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html). In this case, the coercion is both harmless and it would significantly hinder readability if it didn't have auto-referencing on method calls.

Comment: Also note that there is a different between a reference to a mutable value & a mutable reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `save_as_ppm` takes a reference to `self` but I've just passed a mutable `self`.

This is not what's happening here. A [method call expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) uses a resolution algorithm which enables users to call a method without having to explicitly create a suitable borrow of the receiving value. If necessary, *the borrow effectively made will match the requested receiving type*.

In other words, the code

```
inputs.save_as_ppm(&filepath)
```

is equivalent to this call in [fully qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name):

```rust
Layer::save_as_ppm(&inputs, &filepath)
```

Note that an immutable borrow was made directly: there is no conversion between different kinds of borrows, and all of this is inconsequential to the mutability of the binding (`let mut inputs`). Since both immutable and mutable variable bindings can be immutably borrowed, the code complies with the borrow checker and compiles.

As an addendum, nothing would stop you from really passing a mutable reference:

```rust
Layer::save_as_ppm(&mut inputs, &filepath);
```

This works because the mutable reference is [coerced](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/coercions.html) into an immutable reference with the same lifetime. It is one of the enumerated [type coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types) available in Rust.

See also:

- [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)
- [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-between-placing-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the)