# Why I cannot use simple types as mutable reference

Tags: rust

I can use mutable reference for complicated types but not for simple data types. For example `x` (u32) in `myfn`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x: u32 = 10;
    myfn(&mut x);
    println!("{}", x);
}

fn myfn(x: &mut u32) {
    x = 20;
  //^^ expected `&mut u32`, found integer
  // help: consider dereferencing here
  // to assign to the mutable borrowed piece of memory
  // *x = 20;
}
```

Is this happening because the simple type is always a copy? If so, why I can use the reference for immutable.

Comment: you must dereference x, so write `*x = 20`. In the future provide what error compiler gave you back.

Comment: Very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-between-placing-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Added to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `x` is a reference inside `myfn`, you need to dereference it before assignment. You're not assigning to `x`, you're assigning to the value that `x` *refers to*:

```
fn myfn(x: &mut u32) {
    *x = 20;
}
```

The compiler even shows this solution in its error message.

Explicit dereferencing is often unnecessary, for example in method calls, thanks to the `Deref` trait. But if you want to assign a new value, you need the explicit `*` there.

Comment: I'm reading the Rust book. I haven't reached to the dereferencing part yet.